How to resolve an HTTP error 503 reading Yahoo Finance from R?
The following code
rvest::read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VWIUX")

generates

Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.

I know the url is ok because pasting the url "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VWIUX" into the search bar works. How can I make the code work? Thanks.

Most websites will block automation, and it may very well be against their ToS. In this case it seems they employ a User-Agent blacklist:
## Tee pipe only for demonstration purposes
`%T>%` <- magrittr::`%T>%`

## We're Firefox now (or at least some magic words)
UA <- httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 Firefox")

html <- httr::GET("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VWIUX", UA) %T>%
   print() |>
   rvest::read_html()

#> Response [https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VWIUX]
#>   Status: 200
#>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
#>   Size: 1.93 MB
#> <!doctype html>
#>  ...

